# BIND DNS SERVFAIL ERROR

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, windows-vista

I am attempting to setup a bind DNS server for use with a domain I recently registered using No-IP. I registered my DNS server with No-IP using ns1.mydomain.net and ns2.mydomain.net pointing to the exact same IP because I only have one IP to point it to. Then in my db.mydomain.net.txt zone file I put this

```
$TTL 6h
$ORIGIN mydomain.net.
@   IN SOA  ns1.mydomain.net.   hostmaster.mydomain.net. (
        2014062101
        10800
        3600
        604800
        86400 )

@   IN SOA  ns2.mydomain.net.   hostmaster.mydomain.net. (
        2014062102
        10800
        3600
        604800
        86400 )         
IN  NS  ns1.mydomain.net.
IN  NS  ns2.mydomain.net.
ns1 IN  A   1.2.3.4
ns2 IN  A   1.2.3.4
@   IN  A       1.2.3.4
scoopta   IN  A 1.2.3.4
files     IN  A     1.2.3.4
```

My goal is to setup two subdomains not including ns1 and ns2. Those being scoopta.mydomain.net and files.mydomain.net. However it doesn't work and whenever I do

```
nslookup mydomain.net
```

I get a SERVERROR and it doesn't work. I've never used bind before so I honestly have no clue what I'm doing. Thanks. As a disclaimer I do have port 53 TCP and UDP open on my router and I have used http://canyouseeme.org to check if the server is accessible and it is. It's something with my configuration I'm sure.

Comment: What's the actual domain? So many things can have gone wrong here, that it's easier to test if we know the domain. Same for the IP of ns1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one SOA record in a zone file.  Remove the second SOA record.

```
$TTL 6h
$ORIGIN mydomain.net.
@   IN SOA  ns1.mydomain.net.   hostmaster.mydomain.net. (
        2014062101
        10800
        3600
        604800
        86400 )        
IN  NS  ns1.mydomain.net.
IN  NS  ns2.mydomain.net.
ns1 IN  A   1.2.3.4
ns2 IN  A   1.2.3.4
@   IN  A       1.2.3.4
scoopta   IN  A 1.2.3.4
files     IN  A     1.2.3.4
```

Comment: If I only have one SOA then it just fails 100%...I got it kinda sorta working by adding the second

Comment: Part of the problem is No-IP requires two servers but I only have one so I'm not sure how to go about having both ns1 and ns2 configured on the same server. That's why I did the double SOA records

Comment: THANK YOU!!!...I setup a second zone for ns2 and now that I have two zones with one SOA each the server is working perfectly

Comment: Turns out that having the second zone caused ns2.mydomain.net to not be found. I got rid of it and now ns2.mydomain.net returns my IP I just don't know whether or not a DNS request can be made to it. Any light on the subject?

Comment: You should only need one zone.  You can try using dig to check that both are working: `dig @ns2.mydomain.net mydomain.net a`

Comment: Yes both are working. Thank you for the assistance. Like I said I deleted the second zone file because it was actually causing issues. The server is working fine.